# Estimate the sample size needed for a chi-square test comparing four percentages

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, statistical-power

I am trying to compare the percentage of males among four countries using Chi-square test. From a previous similar study, I know that the percentage of males in these four countries are 0, 10%, 30%, and 70%, respectively. Now in our study, I would like to ask: what is the sample size needed to ensure a study power of 0.8 for our chi-square test with P<0.05; in other words, to ensure a power of 0.8 that there is at least one country whose percentage of males is different from either of the other three countries. How should I do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can find online calculator to calculate the sample size for you, for example https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~rollin/stats/ssize/b2.html

Comment: hello, did you really read my post? We have FOUR groups.

Comment: "in other words, to ensure a power of 0.8 that there is at least one country whose percentage of males is different from either of the other three countries." This sentence means: compare highest with lowest ==> two groups.